# WebBrowser Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

How do I stop a new tab from opening google.com automaticaly in visual basic. I need a blank url textbox
This is my code for new tab

```
Private Sub AddTabToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddTabToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim tab As New TabPage
    Dim newtab As New tab
    newtab.Show()
    newtab.TopLevel = False
    newtab.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    tab.Controls.Add(newtab)
    Form1.TabControl1.TabPages.Add(tab)
    Form1.TabControl1.SelectedTab = tab
```

And this is the code when form loads

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim t As New TabPage
    Dim newtab As New tab
    newtab.Show()
    newtab.TopLevel = False
    newtab.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    t.Controls.Add(newtab)
    TabControl1.TabPages.Add(t)

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean here. Are you trying to create a tabbed webbrowser? What kind of design have you made it with? You would need to set the Url property of the webbrowser to nothing and the textbox.text property to nothing

Comment: Yes am making a tabbed webbrowser. But in th meantime I would try and set it to nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted you could allow the user to set their own homepage.

Simply create a button, or an item in the drop down bar that says "Set Homepage"

Create a new setting for your web browser called homePage, set it to string. Do nothing else.

Next create a new form called Homepage and link it to the button you created in step one by double clicking the button and putting

```
homepage.show()
```

in the code for that button.

On the other form you created you need a text box, and a button that says save.

double click the button and put this code in the button's code block.

```
textbox1.text = my.settings.homePage
my.settings.save()
```

Finally on your original browser form, under form1_load put this line of code

```
webbrowser1.navigate(my.settings.homePage)
```

That should work, it did for my browser at least

Answer (score 0):

It won't open a page until you actually set it to open a page. Somewhere in your code you have something that will look similar to

webbrowser1.navigate("www.google.com")

Most likely within your form_load event. Just delete that.

Comment: Thanks Sam I realized that I had made it set in my Homepage Settings. However I would like to just add "www.google.com" when the page starts, without going through the same issues, Any suggestions. Am thinking of an If statement.